# New Lines in MariaDB yields to strange characters in csv export

Tags: csv, mariadb

I have to export data from a table into a CSV file. The output looks like this:

```
SELECT id,duration,description FROM db.entries WHERE id>=2622;
+------+----------+--------------------------------+
| id   | duration | description                    |
+------+----------+--------------------------------+
| 2622 |     1800 | Test
TEst
Teststring         |
| 2623 |     1800 | Normal text entry              |
| 2624 |     1800 | Yet
Another
Line Break
Test |
| 2625 |     1800 | Another normal line text       |
+------+----------+--------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

ID 2622 and ID 2624 contains new lines in the descriptions. The insert into the database is done by an PHP application (if it is relevant).

The code snippet for the export is this:

```
mysql -u root -p$PASSWD -e "SELECT id,duration,description
        INTO OUTFILE '$FILE' FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' ENCLOSED BY '\'' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' \
        FROM db.entries \
        WHERE id>=2622;"
```

If I output the file, it looks like this:

```
\2622'|'1800'|'Test
\Est
Teststring'
'2623'|'1800'|'Normal text entry'
\2624'|'1800'|'Yet
\nother
\ine Break
Test'
'2625'|'1800'|'Another normal line text'
```

All rows with the new lines have additional slashes at the beginning. This could be replaces, but it also replaces regular characters. How can I get a CSV export without these unwanted slashes?

The used system is:

- Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
- mariadb-server-10.6

Comment: I've edited the title and tags to make it more clear that you're using MariaDB, not MySQL. These are two different products. MariaDB started as a fork of MySQL in 2010, but both products have changed in significant ways since then, so they should no longer be considered compatible.

Comment: Try this...
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'

instead of LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'

Comment: @user2260040 The result is the same :-/

Comment: Can you try replacing the newline in the column description with some other character eg. \t and then output to csv?

Comment: please show the results of `select hex(description) from db.entries where id=2622`

Comment: @ysth Thanks, I didn't know about hex(), the result is 546573740D0A544573740D0A54657374737472696E67 . If I see it right, the problematic new line code is 0x0D 0x0A .

Comment: That's CR LF.  I wonder where the Carriage Return is coming from.

Comment: uuuh, nice! I changed it like this: SELECT id,duration,REPLACE(description,CHAR(13), '') and it seems to work. I'm doing some tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is the removement of the carriage return character, which seems to be written to the database by the web application:

```
SELECT id,duration,REPLACE(description,CHAR(13), '') description
    INTO OUTFILE '$FILE' FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' ENCLOSED BY '\'' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' \
    FROM db.entries \
    WHERE id>=2622;
```